# Why does sshfs not work only when called inside an ssh command?

Tags: macos, ssh, virtual-machine, arch-linux, sshfs

*A* is a Mac Os X 10.7.2 host and *B* is an ArchLinux VM running in *A*. I can ssh from *A* to *B* and from *B* to *A* using an authentication key. I want *B* to mount itself in *A* using sshfs when it starts.

Why does this work ...

```
X@B $ ssh A
X@A $ sshfs B: Desktop/B/
X@A $ ls Desktop/B/
Desktop/      Downloads/    Temp/         bin/
```

... and this doesn't?

```
X@B $ ssh -t A "/opt/local/bin/sshfs B: Desktop/B/"
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/X/.ssh/id_dsa': 
Connection to A closed.
-- then back on A: --
X@A $ ls Desktop/B/
[empty]
```

**Why does the first scenario works without any problem when the second does not?**

I also tried the dual operation (mounting A in B instead of B in A) and the second scenario does not work better. I use the -t to be able to type my passphrase and I don't care about typing it for this question (aka don't suggest me to forward my agent it's not the question...).

Here are my versions:

```
X@A $ sshfs -V                                                                                                                                                                                                 
SSHFS version 2.3
fuse4x library version: FUSE 2.8.6 / fuse4x 0.8.13

X@B $ sshfs -V
SSHFS version 2.3
FUSE library version: 2.8.6
fusermount version: 2.8.6
using FUSE kernel interface version 7.12
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have osx at hand, but the reason for your problem is most likely same as why it won't work with linux either.

The problem is that sshfs is connected to a terminal and disconnecting closes said terminal and closes your mount.

This can be tested with:

```
ssh -t A "/opt/local/bin/sshfs B: Desktop/B/ ; sleep 60"
```

and check that mount worked. After 60 seconds it should disappear.

One way to solve this is to use `nohup` or something similar.

```
ssh -t A "nohup /opt/local/bin/sshfs B: Desktop/B/"
```

Please note that you will not see passphrase dialog, but you can still input your passphrase. (Or at least it worked with password)